# Is there a way to do inverse of a group by operation in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame, and a  list of lists, I want each row in the pandas data frame to duplicated as many times in the list and add the list as a new column.

input :

> ```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['row1','row2','row3']})
> ll = [['a','b'],['a','b','c'],[]]
> ```

```
  col1
0  row1
1  row2
2  row3
```

expected result :

> ```
> pd.DataFrame({'col1':['row1','row1','row2','row2','row2','row3'],'col2':['a','b','a','b','c','nan']})
> ```

```
   col1 col2
0  row1    a
1  row1    b
2  row2    a
3  row2    b
4  row2    c
5  row3  nan
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) on a Serie built from `ll`, and `reset_index` like:

```
df = df.join(pd.Series(ll, df.index, name='col2').explode()).reset_index()
print (df)
   col1 col2
0  row1    a
1  row1    b
2  row2    a
3  row2    b
4  row2    c
5  row3  NaN
```

Comment: @cerofrais thanks, but if speed is your concern, I'm not sure that this is he best way

Comment: @cerofrais and I'm not sure there is a faster way than doing `pd.DataFrame([[r, l] for r, l1 in zip(df['col1'],ll) for l in l1], columns = ['col1','col2'])`, similar to the answer of Umbreon29 when the size increase

Comment: This is probably the right solution, didn't know about explode

Comment: @umbreon29 it is kind of new and it is really convenient :)

Answer (score 2):

if u want the last cell empty, u could pass it as a list :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['row1','row2','row3']})
ll = [['a','b'],['a','b','c'],[None]] # or np.nan
```

next is a combination of zip, [product](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), [chain](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to get ur output before reading it into a pandas dataframe :

```
from itertools import product, chain
res = chain.from_iterable(product([first],last)
                          for first, last
                          in zip(df.col1,ll)
                         )

pd.DataFrame(res)

      0     1
0   row1    a
1   row1    b
2   row2    a
3   row2    b
4   row2    c
5   row3    None
```

speed return on this is `373 µs ± 9.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

speed return using @Ben.T's solution : `2.03 ms ± 64.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

speed using @umbreon29's approach : `460 µs ± 7.41 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

of course, this is a very tiny dataset. proper test on a large dataset should be more definite

Comment: nice and yes it is faster on small size, but two things: first you need to have `[None]` or `[np.nan]` instead of `[]` otherwise it does not give the expected output and second, when the size increases, it does not go faster than the list comprehension :)

Comment: yea, that's the caveat. compared to the list comprehension. for the speed test i'd love to see it for larget datasets. who knows, there might be some optimization that someone else might bring to the table.

Comment: I tried with `df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'col1':['row1','row2','row3']})]*1000, ignore_index=True)` and `ll = [['a','b'],['a','b','c'],[None]]*1000`, and this method seems slower than the list comprehension of about 25%, but explode is worst :)

Comment: Nice. I’ll play with it wen I’m back on my pc.

Comment: u'll have to share ur list comprehension code. cos i tried it out and using the itertools/generator expressions is faster.

Comment: I used this one `pd.DataFrame([[r, l] for r, l1 in zip(df['col1'],ll) for l in l1])` that give the same result as yours

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
rows = ['row1','row2','row3']
ll = [['a','b'],['a','b','c'],[]]

t = []
for r, l1 in zip(rows,ll):
   for l2 in l1: t.append([r,l2])

df = pd.DataFrame(t, columns = ['col1','col2'])
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I already did this but i was looking for a more efficient way without these loops, any pythonic way to improve speed. maybe an inbuilt pandas method or a vectorized approach or somethingelse.